# How can I use document.querySelector to select this class name with a space in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="PrmryBtnMed"
 id = "VERYLONGTEXT"

onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(); return false;"><span>Dispatch to this address</span></a>
```

I have been using

```
var inPage = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('text to search') > 0,
    el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed");

if (inPage && el) el.click();
```

But now, the class name has changed: there’s a space and some new text in the class name:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="PrmryBtnMed ApricotWheat"
 id = "VERYLONGTEXT"
onclick="ApricotWheat(this); return false;"><span>Dispatch to this address</span></a>
```

How can I change `el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed");`
to find the right class?

I tried using `el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat");` but that didn’t work.

Next, I tried to add a space (and escape using a backslash): `el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed\ ApricotWheat");` but that didn’t work either.

So, I wondered if I could use `%20` for the space.. but no luck.

I’d be very grateful for some help! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There can be no spaces in a class name ... there are two different classes in the element ... use ".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat"

Comment: `document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat")` should work. [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/gyk26nbb/). But you can't have a space in a class name; those are actually two classes, (`PrmryBtnMed` is one and `ApricotWheat` is another).

Comment: I forgot to add there’s one other subtle change, which i’ve now edited to include: `onclick=“ApricotWheat(this); return false;”>` (Instead of `onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(); return false;”>`)

Comment: @Ted: Those fancy quotes are invalid for quoting attribute values in HTML. The quotes must be normal single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Classes can't have spaces, what you have there is an element with **two separate** classes on it. To select an element with two classes, you use a compound class selector:

```
 document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat");
```

That selects the first element in the document that has **both** the `PrmryBtnMed` class and the `ApricotWheat` class. Note that it doesn't matter what order those classes appear in in the `class` attribute, and it doesn't matter whether there are also other classes present. It would match any of these, for instance:

```
<div class="PrmryBtnMed ApricotWheat">...</div>
```

or

```
<div class="ApricotWheat PrmryBtnMed">...</div>
```

or

```
<div class="PrmryBtnMed foo baz ApricotWheat">...</div>
```

etc.

Also note that the quotes you're using around HTML attributes are sporatically invalid; the quotes around attributes **must** be normal, boring, single (`'`) or double (`"`), they can't be fancy quotes.

Live example with quotes fixed and using the selector above:

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat");
if (el) {
  el.click();
}

function ApricotWheat(element) {
  alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="PrmryBtnMed ApricotWheat" id="VERYLONGTEXT" onclick="ApricotWheat(this); return false;"><span>Dispatch to this address</span></a>
```

Comment: Good spot with the fancy quotes, I'm not sure how that happened! You're quite right, they should absolutely only be `'` or `"` !

Comment: Thanks for your example, but what happened to this bit from the first line: `'text to search` ? (I use that to test for the presence of a certain text on the page - if it is there, then I want the button to be clicked)

Comment: @Ted: It was irrelevant to the example.

Comment: (I am very grateful for your explanations!)

Answer (score 7):

There can be no spaces in a class name ... there are two different classes in the element ... use `".PrmryBtnMed.ApricotWheat"`

Comment: Thanks! But it still isn’t working, so it must be because `if (inPage && el) el.click();` no longer does the desired action. I wonder if it’s something to do with `onclick=“ApricotWheat(this); return false;”>` ?

Comment: urw ... but plz use event listeners instead of onclick attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

`class="PrmryBtnMed ApricotWheat"` In this instance you have 2 different classes,
so you need to use the AND condition in your query.